# How to squeeze the new format list from a old format list

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk

I am trying to generate the new format lists from a old format list.

A original format list file as below.

```
#cat hub_dev_list

category,region,ip,host,os
hub,central,10.10.10.10,NWTTHC-1-01,CiscoIOS
hub,central,172.11.11.11,NWTCOT-1-LRE01,CiscoIOS
hub,central,10.19.19.19,NWTCOT-1-02,Juniper
hub,chai-wan,10.1.1.1,CNCSFC-1-01,HuaweiVRP
hub,chai-wan,10.3.3.3,CNCMIA-1-LRE02,CiscoIOS
hub,chai-wan,10.4.4.4,CNCSFC-1-HWV201,Juniper
hub,idc,192.9.9.9,SWiDC10-J3-28,CiscoIOS
hub,idc,192.5.5.5,SwiDC-J325-06,Juniper
hub,idc,10.9.9.9,SWiDC19-J3-16,Juniper
```

Can this be done with any utility in Linux??

Classify the region & OS.

Desired output format as below:

Save to cisco_hubcentral__list

```
#cat cisco_hubcentral__list
NWTTHC-1-01,10.10.10.10
NWTCOT-1-LRE01,172.11.11.11
```

Save to juniper_hubcentral__list

```
#cat juniper_hubcentral__list
NWTCOT-1-02,10.19.19.19
```

Save to huawei_hubchaiwan_list

```
#cat huawei_hubchaiwan_list
CNCSFC-1-01,10.1.1.1
```

Save to cisco_hubchaiwan_list

```
#cat cisco_hubchaiwan_list
CNCMIA-1-LRE02,10.3.3.3
```

Save to juniper_hubchaiwan_list

```
#cat juniper_hubchaiwan_list
CNCSFC-1-HWV201,10.4.4.4
```

Save to cisco_hub_idc_list

```
#cat cisco_hubidc_list
SWiDC10-J3-28,192.9.9.9
```

Save to juniper_hub_idc_list

```
#cat juniper_hubidc_list
SwiDC-J325-06,192.5.5.5
SWiDC19-J3-16,10.9.9.9
```

Comment: It is always recommended to post your efforts in your post which you have put in order to solve your problem.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {file=$NF"_"$1 $2"_list";print >> file;close(file)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                         ##Starting BEGIN section for awk program here.
  FS=OFS=","                   ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here.
}                              ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN section here.
{                              ##Starting BLOCK for main Input_file reading here.
  file=$NF"_"$1 $2"_list"      ##Creating variable file whose value is $NF(last field)_first field space 2nd field then _list as per OP given format.
  print >> file                ##Printing current line to output file whose name is created previous line.
  close(file)                  ##Using close function of OOTB function of awk to close this output file in backend to avoid "TOO many files opened".
}                              ##Closing main BLOCK here.
'  Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

OR in case your Input_file's `$NF` is sorted with last field and having continous values in last field then we need not to close output file each line we can close it whenever an entry is different from current $NF.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} prev!=$NF{close(file);prev=$NF} {file=$NF"_"$1 $2"_list";print > file}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                             ##Starting BEGIN section here for this code.
  FS=OFS=","                       ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here.
}                                  ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN section here.
prev!=$NF{                         ##Checking condition if variable prev is NOT equal to $NF then do following.
  close(file)                      ##Using close to close file, which is passed in form of file variable to this function, to avoid "TOO many files opened."
  prev=$NF                         ##Setting prev to $NF here.
}                                  ##Closing BLOCK for condition for prev!=$NF condition here.
{                                  ##Starting main BLOCK here.
  file=$NF"_"$1 $2"_list"          ##Creating variable named file whose value is $NF(last field)_first field space 2nd field then _list as per OP given format.
  print > file                     ##Printing current line value to output file.
}                                  ##Closing main BLOCK here.
'  Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @Danny Luk, Could you please do let me know if this helps you?